# Preventing from adding data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a directory where u can add yourself by entering the code sms. After entering the correct code sms, it checks if code exist in the database, then remove entered code from DB and add data from form. Now I have a problem because I do not know how to prevent from adding data into the database, when the given code is incorrect.
At the moment, it looks like this:

```
    if ($sum != $val1+$val2) {   //simple captcha
            echo '<div id="message_position_capreg"><p class="error_form"><font color="red">Incorrect. Try again</font></p></div>';
        }
        else {
            if ($_POST['code']){
    $code=$_POST['code'];

    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM code_sms WHERE code = %s", $cd);
    $check_code = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if ($check_code>0)  {

    $wpdb->delete( 'code_sms', array( 'code' => $code ) );


    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_formm"] ) && $_POST["company_nip"] && $_POST["company_name"] != "" ){
                $company_nip = strip_tags($_POST["company_nip"], "");
                $company_name = strip_tags($_POST["company_name"], "");
    $result = $wpdb->insert( 
                    'test', 
                    array( 
                        'company_nip' => $company_nip, 'company_name' => $company_name)
                );

    if (!$result) {
            echo '<div>
    ERROR</div>';
            }
            else {

             echo '<div>
    Succes</div>';
            }
        }
         }
}
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I editted my code, like @thephatp said, and it's now working :)

Comment: See my updated answer below. You have to check the row count rather than test just against the results set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically checking "if sms_code exists in database" then "remove code; insert form data."

However, you're closing your if statement *prior* to adding the form data. Move your `}` that closes your if statement as shown below. That way, if the sms_code is incorrect, you do not process the form data if statement & insert.

Also, your `$check_code` variable is not the number of rows, but rather a results set. This result set will only be `FALSE` if the query resulted in an error. 
See the documentation for get_result here: 
[mysqli_stmt_get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

> Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE for other
>   DML queries or on failure. The mysqli_errno() function can be used to
>   distinguish between the two types of failure.

You need to check the results set for the number of rows and test against that in the if statement. Code below has been updated.

```
  if ($sum != $val1+$val2) {   //simple captcha
            echo '<div id="message_position_capreg"><p class="error_form"><font color="red">Incorrect. Try again</font></p></div>';
        }
        else {
            if ($_POST['code']){
    $code=$_POST['code'];

    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM code_sms WHERE code = %s", $cd);

   $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

   /* Get the number of rows */
   $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num_of_rows>0)  {

        $wpdb->delete( 'code_sms', array( 'code' => $code ) );

        if ( isset( $_POST["submit_formm"] ) && $_POST["company_nip"] && $_POST["company_name"] != "" ){
                    $company_nip = strip_tags($_POST["company_nip"], "");
                    $company_name = strip_tags($_POST["company_name"], "");
            $result = $wpdb->insert( 
                        'test', 
                        array( 
                            'company_nip' => $company_nip, 'company_name' => $company_name)
                    );

            if (!$result) {
                echo '<div>
                ERROR</div>';
            }
            else {

                 echo '<div>
                Succes</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did like u said, but its still somehow add this data, and give "Succes".

Comment: @ZYWIEC, updated the code above. I didn't look carefully enough the first time--your `$check_code` variable is a results set, which will be `TRUE` as long as the query doesn't result in an error. It is _not_ the number of rows returned from the result set. Update the code above. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the code that adds data to the database inside the `if` condition where the sms code has been validated true - `if ($check_code>0)  {` - just append it right after the code sms delete.

```
if ($sum != $val1+$val2) {   //simple captcha
        echo '<div id="message_position_capreg"><p class="error_form"><font color="red">Incorrect. Try again</font></p></div>';
    }
    else {
        if ($_POST['code']){
$code=$_POST['code'];

global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM code_sms WHERE code = %s", $cd);
$check_code = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if ($check_code>0)  {

$wpdb->delete( 'code_sms', array( 'code' => $code ) );

// Removed closing braces here

if ( isset( $_POST["submit_formm"] ) && $_POST["company_nip"] && $_POST["company_name"] != "" ){
            $company_nip = strip_tags($_POST["company_nip"], "");
            $company_name = strip_tags($_POST["company_name"], "");
$result = $wpdb->insert( 
                'test', 
                array( 
                    'company_nip' => $company_nip, 'company_name' => $company_name)
            );

if (!$result) {
        echo '<div>
ERROR</div>';
        }
        else {

         echo '<div>
Succes</div>';
        }
    }
     }
}

} // Added closing braces here
```

Comment: Ok, i did that, but its still adding :(

Comment: `$check_code` is a resultset not the number of rows returned. You have to pull the number of rows from the resultset first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($sum != $val1+$val2) {   //simple captcha
        echo '<div id="message_position_capreg"><p class="error_form"><font color="red">Incorrect. Try again</font></p></div>';
    }
    else {
        if ($_POST['code']){
$code=$_POST['code'];

global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM code_sms WHERE code = %s", $cd);
$check_code = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if ($check_code>0)  {

$wpdb->delete( 'code_sms', array( 'code' => $code ) );


    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_formm"] ) && $_POST["company_nip"] && $_POST["company_name"] != "" ){
            $company_nip = strip_tags($_POST["company_nip"], "");
            $company_name = strip_tags($_POST["company_name"], "");
    $result = $wpdb->insert( 
                'test', 
                array( 
                    'company_nip' => $company_nip, 'company_name' => $company_name)
            );

    if (!$result) {
        echo '<div>
    ERROR</div>';
        }
        else {

         echo '<div>
    Succes</div>';
            }
        }
     }
  }
  else
  {
      echo '<div>
    ERROR WRONG CODE</div>';
  }
}
```